# How to write route name with parameter in laravel controller with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I made a live search with laravel and ajax so in my `table` `td` when I tried to pass named route with parameter inside  `onClick="location.href=''"` in my controller, it does not work. But named route without parameter have no problem. How can I fix this?

> My controller:

```
   function action(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
         $output = '';
         if($query != '')
         {
          $data = DB::table('banners')
            ->where('id', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('Caption_Heading', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('Caption_Description', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->get();
            
         }
         else
         {
          $data = DB::table('banners')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->get();
         }
         $total_row = $data->count();

         if($total_row > 0)
         {
          foreach($data as $row)
          {
            $route = route('banners.edit',$banner);
           $output .= '

           <tr>
           <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" class="selectbox" value="'.$row->id.'" onchange="change()"></th>
            <td onClick="location.href='.$route.'" style="cursor: pointer">'.$row->id.'</td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer"><img src="/storage/'.$row->Banner_Image.'"  alt="'.$row->Caption_Heading.'" class="img-thumbnail" width="70px" height="100px"></td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">'.$row->Caption_Description.'</td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">'.$row->Caption_Description.'</td>
           </tr>
           ';
          }
         }
         else
         {
          $output = '
          <tr>
           <td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
          </tr>
          ';
         }
         $data = array(
          'table_data'  => $output,
          'total_data'  => $total_row
         );
   
         echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
```

> My web.php:

```
        Route::prefix('banners')->group(function() {
            Route::get('/', 'AdminVisible\BannerController@index')->name('banner');
            Route::get('/action', 'AdminVisible\BannerController@action')->name('banner.action');
            Route::get('/create', 'AdminVisible\BannerController@create')->name('banners.create');
            Route::post('/create', 'AdminVisible\BannerController@store')->name('banners.store');
            Route::delete('/delete','AdminVisible\BannerController@delete')->name('banners.delete');
            Route::get('{banner}/edit', 'AdminVisible\BannerController@edit')->name('banners.edit');
            Route::patch('/{banner}', 'AdminVisible\BannerController@update')->name('banners.update');
        });
```

My js file:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
  
  fetch_customer_data();
  
  function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"{{ route('banner.action') }}",
    method:'GET',
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
     $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
    }
   })
  }
  
  $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
   var query = $(this).val();
   fetch_customer_data(query);
  });
  });
```

Comment: Make your route parameter optional. Post your route code and the controller code with your quesion, so we can help

Comment: @sta sure wait a minute. Edit: I added it above

Comment: `$request->get('query')` Do you get it null if you try to search with param ?

Comment: I think `data:{query:query},` will be `data: { query: $("#search").val() },`

Comment: @sta ok let me try

Comment: @sta it shows blank.

Comment: @sta i am asking a way to put route name with parameter inside `onClick="location.href=' '` other than that the search functionality is working

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Where exactly does you application go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$banner` is never initialized, so I´m gessing something like

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
    $banner = ['banner' => $row->id];
    $route = route('banners.edit',$banner);
    ....
}
```

Comment: @JarioNavaMagana thanks I had been searching for quite some time for a solution. It worked

Comment: there seems to be a slight problem: It should be like this `onclick="location.href=' ' "` but it seems we cannot put it like this `' '.$route.' '`

Comment: just use backslash `<td onClick="location.href=\''.$route.'\' "`

Comment: can you check this question for me: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63591495/i-am-getting-500-internal-error-when-trying-to-pass-named-route-in-my-controller?noredirect=1#comment112493184_63591495]